# How to grab a word or character and wrap it in a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to find a particular character in a div and wrap it in a `span` tag.

I thought I could use something like:

```
$('.breadcrumb:contains("»")').replaceWith('<span>»</span>');
```

But this changes the whole breadcrumb div.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`.replaceWith` only works on nodes. You need the string method `.replace()` instead:

```
var $bc = $('.breadcrumb');
$bc.html($bc.text().replace('»', '<span>»</span>'));
```

Like Mr. Craver suggested, you can also call:

```
$bc.html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace('»', '<span>»</span>');
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jwJKr/

Comment: This would replace all instances, be careful...if there's more than one `.breadcrumb` this would be very undesirable :)

Comment: I guess for an example, this is fair enough

Comment: `.text()` and `.html()` both take a function ;)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The only issue using the above is I seem to lose my anchor tags/links on other breadcrumb items. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, it only changes the first instance of it. E.g.:

<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> <span>»</span> <a href="/food-drink" title="Food &amp; Drink">Food &amp; Drink</a> » Dolor Sit</div>

Answer (score 2):

```
var $bc = $('.breadcrumb');
$bc.html($bc.text().split('»').join('<span>»</span>'));
```

Works better to replace all characters.

Comment: /agree But also note that using `.text` wipes out and child tags. You can just use `.html` both to get the contained html and to replace it and the tags contained within will persist.